# Error using aurelia "buscar' to be a function"

Tags: aurelia2

Help me please, Why don't function this. excuse me my english I'm learn english and aurelia 2

[image]

Comment: Please post the code and the error instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I found the solution

The main component has
`<import from ="./busqueda.html" />`

```
and must be
```

`<import from ="./busqueda" />`